# Regex in Vi: How does one use character classes inside groups? (e.g. [\s\w])

Tags: regular-expression

In Vim, the character class `\s` matches any whitespace character. When I'm using those special characters in groups e.g. `[\s\w]` it does not match any single whitespace or word character, it does match `s` or `w`.

How does one use character classes inside groups?

Comment: Unlike some implementations of regular expression engines, Vim's doesn't seem to support that notation. `[[:space:][:alnum:]_]` can be used to approximate the collection of `\s` and `\w`, though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's not a group, it's a range, and in Vim you can't use character classes (although it's possible in other regex implementations, e.g. in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142440/python-regex-including-whitespace-inside-character-range)). You'll have to use an [alternation](http://vimregex.com/#alternations) instead:

```
/\(\w\|\s\)
```

or:

```
/\v(\s|\w)
```

(or, the [solution proposed](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4505/1111) by [Peter Lewerin](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/2942/peter-lewerin)).

Comment: Just because one can construct an invalid range in a character class doesn't mean that it shouldn't be possible to use something like `\s` in a character class.  Vim's regex implementation happens to have made that choice, but other implementations allow you to use `[\s]`.

Comment: @VanLaser If you edit the answer with this info ([\s] is a possibilty in other regex-implementations but not in vim) i'll accept your answer!

Comment: (all right, added)

Answer (score 15):

Unlike some implementations of regular expression engines, Vim's doesn't seem to support that notation (`[\s\w]`) in collections. One can use [POSIX character class expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes), though.

- `[:blank:]` is the same as `\s`.
- `[:space:]` matches a greater number of whitespace characters than `\s` does, and seems to be equivalent to `\_s`.
- `[:alnum:]` approximates  `\w`, but does not match the underscore (`_`).

So the collection you wanted could be written as `[[:blank:][:alnum:]_]` or `[[:space:][:alnum:]_]`.

I haven't verified this by testing, but it is documented in `:h regexp`, `:h /character-classes`, and `:h /collection`.

Portability note: In other regex engines, `\s` is typically the same as `[:space:]` (or `\_s`) is in Vim.