# exclude character classes inside [] in a regex

Tags: regular-expression

I want to write a regex that finds words contained in brackets, like `[word]`. The words are not allowed to contain spaces or the characters `[` or `]`.

I tried with

```
\[[^\[\]\s]\+]
```

But applied to the string

```
'foo [first] bar [second] baz [third] and [fourth]'
```

it only finds `[third]` and `[fourth]`.

I don't understand why. What is wrong with the regex? It is not *totally* wrong as it still finds some matches. But not all I would expect.

**EDIT**: Ok, I found it. `\s` is not working as expected. I intended to use it as a character class, but it is obiously interpreted as the separate characters `\` and `s`. As `first` and `second` both contain the `s` they don't match.

Now: How do I match character classes inside a `[]` construct?
(I updated the title accordingly.)

**EDIT2**: [Regex in Vi: How does one use character classes inside groups? (e.g. [\s\w])](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4116/21417)
 basically askes the same. But there is no answer about how to *exclude* character classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Character classes such as `\s` are not acceptable inside a `[...]` group (with or without the `^`, but character class expressions such as [`[:space:]`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%5B%3Aspace%3A%5D) actually are. So you can use the following:

```
/\[[^\[\][:space:]]\+]
```

This will correctly match `[first]` and `[second]`, besides `[third]` and `[fourth]` in your original regular expression.

Note that there's a small difference between `\s` and `[:space:]`. While the former only matches space and tab, the latter matches all whitespace characters: space, tab, CR, NL, vertical tab and form feed. For most cases (including this one), that doesn't really affect the end result. (In fact, you could argue you get a better regex from `[:space:]`, since it matches more characters that *should* qualify as whitespace.)

There are similar `[:...:]` sequences for other corresponding matches, for example `[:keyword:]` which is the same as `\k`. But some, such as `\w`, don't have a *direct* counterpart, but it's actually just `[:alnum:]` plus underscore, so `[[:alnum:]_]` should do it, or `[^[:alnum:]_]` to match `\W`.