# How to select a regexp group in vim?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, search

I want to select/visualize a regexp GROUP in a vim regexp expression in vim.

By example I would like to highlight (search) a span of characters inside square brackets, having this line:

```
bla bla bla [Corso De Stefanis 88 interno 4](address) blabla
```

I would like to just select this sequence of chars:

```
Corso De Stefanis 88 interno 4
```

So I tried the regexp

```
/\[\(.\{-}\)\]
```

Where the aim is to have the regexp GROUP `\(.\{-}\)` contained in sqare brackets. But in this case I select the pattern including square brackets (see screeenshot).

And if I specify the referenced group with `\1`, the search fails:

```
/\[\(.\{-}\)\]\1
```

Where I'm wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

reading here:
[exclude character classes inside [] in a regex](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25584/exclude-character-classes-inside-in-a-regex?rq=1)

and here:
[exclude character classes inside [] in a regex](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25584/exclude-character-classes-inside-in-a-regex?rq=1)

I find the solution, that's:

```
/\[\zs.\{-}\ze\]
```

In a sense, capture group seems not working, but you can select the "group" preceding sequence by `\zs` and finishing with `\ze`. vim regexp syntax is weird for me.

Comment: Try `:help pattern`. Searches can include capture groups, but not _backreferences_ (the `\1`, etc.). `\zs` and `\ze` set boundaries for the final "match." Backreferences are still used in substitution commands, however (`:help :substitute` and `:help sub-replace-special`).

Comment: Thanks. BTW, My need is related to my vim plugin Highlight.vim. See example s and screenshots here: https://github.com/solyarisoftware/Highlight.vim/tree/master/screenshots#43-highlight-entity-valuename-couples-with-different-colors-by-entity